# How to transfer Windows Netbeans projects into linux Netbeans

Tags: java, linux, windows, netbeans, migrating

I recently moved from Windows to Fedora and now I need to open and work on my projects in linux. Can you tell me how can I move it into linux?

Comment: If it is small, copy the sources directly. If it is big project, check it in repository like git/svn from window and fetch it in fedora worksapce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different methods. Either:

1. Copy the entire project folder and then choose `File`->`Open Project` and select the path where you have stored it on linux.
2. Or you can previously `export` your project to `zip` file from `File`->`Export Project` and then import it from linux from `File`->`Import Project`.

NetBeans saves all your project settings inside `nbproject` folder which resides in the root of your project directory.